# Морской бой с# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю морской бой с двумя ботами на WinForms,которые играют друг с другом.Но результаты все естественно выводятся сразу,т.к. задержки между выстрелами нет.Надо бы сделать задержку,чтобы видно было каждый ход.Thread.sleep() вызывает зависания,если его применить. Скорее всего тут много потоков нужно,но я плохо разбираюсь в этом, поэтому прошу помощи.

SeaFight.cs:

```
namespace SeaFight
{
    class Map
    {
        public static int mapSize = 10;
        public static int cellSize = 30;
        public static Label game_over;
        public static int[,] myMap = new int[mapSize, mapSize];
        public static int[,] enemyMap = new int[mapSize, mapSize];

        public static Button[,] myButtons = new Button[mapSize, mapSize];
        public static Button[,] enemyButtons = new Button[mapSize, mapSize];

        public static void initShips(Ship[] ships)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    ships[i] = new Ship(4, rnd.Next(2) > 0);
                }
                else if (i > 0 && i <= 2)
                {
                    ships[i] = new Ship(3, rnd.Next(2) > 0);
                }
                else if (i > 2 && i <= 5)
                {
                    ships[i] = new Ship(2, rnd.Next(2) > 0);
                }
                else if (i > 5 && i < 10)
                {
                    ships[i] = new Ship(1, rnd.Next(2) > 0);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void positionShips(Ship[] ships, int[,] map)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10;)
            {
                if (ships[i].setPosition(rnd.Next(1, 11), rnd.Next(1, 11), map)) i++;
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class SeaFight : Form
    {
    
        public string alphabet = "АБВГДЕЖЗИК";
       
        public bool isPlaying = false;

        public Bot bot;

        public SeaFight()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Морской бой";
            Init();
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            isPlaying = false;
            CreateMaps();
            bot = new Bot();
            ConfigureShips();
            Map.enemyMap = bot.ConfigureShips();
        }

        public void CreateMaps()
        {
            this.Width = Map.mapSize * 2 * Map.cellSize + 50;
            this.Height = (Map.mapSize + 3) * Map.cellSize + 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < Map.mapSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Map.mapSize; j++)
                {
                    Map.myMap[i, j] = 0;

                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Location = new Point(j * Map.cellSize, i * Map.cellSize);
                    button.Size = new Size(Map.cellSize, Map.cellSize);
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    if (j == 0 || i == 0)
                    {
                        button.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        if (i == 0 && j > 0)
                            button.Text = alphabet[j - 1].ToString();
                        if (j == 0 && i > 0)
                            button.Text = i.ToString();
                    }
                    Map.myButtons[i, j] = button;
                    this.Controls.Add(button);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Map.mapSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Map.mapSize; j++)
                {
                    Map.myMap[i, j] = 0;
                    Map.enemyMap[i, j] = 0;

                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Location = new Point(320 + j * Map.cellSize, i * Map.cellSize);
                    button.Size = new Size(Map.cellSize, Map.cellSize);
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    if (j == 0 || i == 0)
                    {
                        button.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        if (i == 0 && j > 0)
                            button.Text = alphabet[j - 1].ToString();
                        if (j == 0 && i > 0)
                            button.Text = i.ToString();
                    }
                    Map.enemyButtons[i, j] = button;
                    this.Controls.Add(button);
                }
            }
            Label map1 = new Label();
            map1.Text = "Player's map";
            map1.Location = new Point((Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize / 2) - 40, Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize + 10);
            this.Controls.Add(map1);

            Label map2 = new Label();
            map2.Text = "Enemy's map";
            map2.Location = new Point(280 + Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize / 2, Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize + 10);
            this.Controls.Add(map2);

            Map.game_over = new Label();
            Map.game_over.Location = new Point(120 + Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize / 2, Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize + 60);
            this.Controls.Add(Map.game_over);

            Button clear = new Button();
            clear.Height = 30;
            clear.Text = "New game";
            clear.Location = new Point(280 + Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize / 2, Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize + 40);
            clear.Click += Clear_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(clear);

            Button startButton = new Button();
            startButton.Height = 30;
            startButton.Text = "Начать";
            startButton.Click += Start;
            startButton.Location = new Point((Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize / 2) - 40, Map.mapSize * Map.cellSize + 40);
            this.Controls.Add(startButton);
        }

        private void Clear_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();
            Init();
        }

        public void Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            PlayerShoot();
        }

        public bool CheckIfMapIsNotEmpty()//is map empty
        {
            bool isEmpty1 = true;
            bool isEmpty2 = true;
            for (int i = 1; i < Map.mapSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < Map.mapSize; j++)
                {
                    if (Map.myMap[i, j] != 0)
                        isEmpty1 = false;
                    if (Map.enemyMap[i, j] != 0)
                        isEmpty2 = false;
                }
            }
            if (isEmpty1 || isEmpty2)
                return false;
            else return true;
        }

        public int[,] ConfigureShips()
        {
            Ship[] ships = new Ship[10];
            Map.initShips(ships);
            Map.positionShips(ships, Map.myMap);
            return Map.myMap;
        }


        public void PlayerShoot()
        {
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                while (Map.game_over.Text == "")
                {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int posX = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);
                    int posY = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);

                    while (Map.enemyButtons[posX, posY].BackColor == Color.Blue || Map.enemyButtons[posX, posY].BackColor == Color.Black)
                    {
                        posX = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);
                        posY = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);
                    }
                    Button pressedButton = Map.enemyButtons[posX, posY];
                    bool playerTurn = Shoot(pressedButton);

                    bool you_win = true;

                    bool enemy_win = true;

                    for (int i = 0; i < Map.mapSize - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Map.mapSize - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (Map.myMap[i, j] == 1 && Map.myButtons[i, j].Text != "X")//если найден неподбитый корабль
                            {
                                you_win = false;
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < Map.mapSize - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Map.mapSize - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (Map.enemyMap[i, j] == 1 && Map.enemyButtons[i, j].Text != "X")//если найден неподбитый корабль
                            {
                                enemy_win = false;
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }


                    if (you_win || enemy_win)
                    {
                        if (you_win)
                        {
                            Map.game_over.Text = "Bot №1 win";
                            Map.game_over.BackColor = Color.Green;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (enemy_win)
                        {
                            Map.game_over.Text = "Bot №2 win";
                            Map.game_over.BackColor = Color.Green;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
               
            }
               
          
            
        }

     


        public bool Shoot(Button pressedButton)
        {
            bool hit = false;
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                int delta = 0;
                if (pressedButton.Location.X > 320)
                    delta = 320;
                if (Map.enemyMap[pressedButton.Location.Y / Map.cellSize, (pressedButton.Location.X - delta) / Map.cellSize] != 0)
                {
                    hit = true;
                    Map.enemyMap[pressedButton.Location.Y / Map.cellSize, (pressedButton.Location.X - delta) / Map.cellSize] = 0;
                    pressedButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    pressedButton.Text = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    hit = false;
                    if (pressedButton.BackColor != Color.Black&& pressedButton.BackColor != Color.Red) bot.Shoot();
                    if (pressedButton.BackColor!=Color.Red) pressedButton.BackColor = Color.Black;

                }
            }
            return hit;
        }
    }
}
```

Bot.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace SeaFight
    {
        public class Bot
        {
            public int[,] myMap = new int[Map.mapSize, Map.mapSize];//bot`s map
            public int[,] enemyMap = new int[Map.mapSize, Map.mapSize];//player`s map

            public Button[,] myButtons = new Button[Map.mapSize, Map.mapSize];//bot's cells
            public Button[,] enemyButtons = new Button[Map.mapSize, Map.mapSize];//player's cells

            public Bot()
            {
                this.myMap = Map.enemyMap;
                this.enemyMap = Map.myMap;
                this.enemyButtons = Map.myButtons;
                this.myButtons = Map.enemyButtons;
            }

            public bool IsInsideMap(int i, int j)//check valid cell
            {
                if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= Map.mapSize || j >= Map.mapSize)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            public bool IsEmpty(int i, int j, int length)//check empty cell
            {
                bool isEmpty = true;

                for (int k = j; k < j + length; k++)
                {
                    if (myMap[i, k] != 0)
                    {
                        isEmpty = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return isEmpty;
            }

       
        public int[,] ConfigureShips()
        {
            Ship[] ships = new Ship[10];
            Map.initShips(ships);
            Map.positionShips(ships, myMap);
            return myMap;
        }


            public bool Shoot()
            {
                bool hit = false;
                Random r = new Random();

                int posX = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);
                int posY = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);

                while (enemyButtons[posX, posY].BackColor == Color.Blue || enemyButtons[posX, posY].BackColor == Color.Black)
                {
                    posX = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);
                    posY = r.Next(1, Map.mapSize);
                }

                if (enemyMap[posX, posY] != 0)
                {
                    hit = true;
                    enemyMap[posX, posY] = 0;
                    enemyButtons[posX, posY].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    enemyButtons[posX, posY].Text = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    hit = false;
                    enemyButtons[posX, posY].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            if (hit) {
                Shoot();
            }
          
                return hit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ship.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SeaFight
{
    class Ship
    {
        private int[,] configMap;
        private int size;
        private bool horizont;
        public bool Horizont
        {
            get { return horizont; }
            set { horizont = value; }
        }
        public Ship(int size, bool horizont) {
            this.size = size;
            configMap = new int[10, 10];
            this.horizont = horizont;
            clearShip();
        }
        public bool setPosition(int x, int y, int[,] map) // set x,y from 1 to 10
        {

            if (map[y-1, x-1] != 1 && size != 1)
            {

                if (horizont)
                {
                    if ((x + size) < 10 - 1)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                            if (scanAround(x + i, y, map) == false)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                            configMap[y, x + i] = 1;
                        }
                        setMap(map);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((y + size) < 10 - 1)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                            if (scanAround(x, y + i, map) == false)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                           configMap[y + i, x] = 1;
                        }
                        setMap(map);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (map[y-1, x-1] != 1 && size == 1)
            {
                if (scanAround(x, y, map))
                {
                    configMap[y, x] = 1;
                    setMap(map);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        public int[,] getConfigMap() {
            return configMap;
        }
        private bool scanAround(int x, int y, int[,] map) {
            try
            {
                if (
                           map[y, x + 1] != 1 && map[y + 1, x + 1] != 1 &&
                           map[y + 1, x] != 1 && map[y + 1, x - 1] != 1 &&
                           map[y, x - 1] != 1 && map[y - 1, x - 1] != 1 &&
                           map[y - 1, x] != 1 && map[y - 1, x + 1] != 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ) { }
            return false;
        }
        public void setMap(int[,] map)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < 10 - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < 10 - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (getConfigMap()[i, j] == 1)
                        map[i, j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        public void clearShip() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <10; j++)
                {
                    configMap[j, i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(...)` => `await Task.Delay(...)`

Comment: Я вызвал данную функцию в методе Shoot в SeaFight.Соответственно поменял тип возвращаемого значения на Task<bool>, но окно зависло после начала игры. Вылезло предупреждение еще "Поскольку этот вызов не ожидается, выполнение текущего метода продолжается до завершения вызова. Попробуйте применить оператор await к результату вызова"

Comment: ну так `Попробуйте применить оператор await к результату вызова`

Comment: он не применяется к обычному bool,а чтобы инициализировать Task<bool> нужен какой-то метод вроде,хотя я не разбираюсь